# azure login in cmd works but powershell fails - behind company proxy

Tags: azure, powershell, cmd

I try to login to azure with

```
az login
```

this does not work behind our proxy and I get something like:

```
Error occurred in request., ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tenants?api-version=2016-06-01 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0568A070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

In cmd therefor I execute the following commands

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80
az login
```

And I get my subscriptions and all works.

Now as most of Azure documentation is used within powershell I tried above way and It did not work. As obviously, setting proxy works different in powershell. So I executed following:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy "myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80"
az login
```

This gives same result as `az login` without proxy in cmd.

Can anyone hint me to the right direction, what setting I need to undertake to use azure cli with powershell?

Comment: I think you could try to set the proxy in the environment follow the steps in [Setting https_proxy in Windows](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html#windows).

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but If I set that proxy I can not reach other needed services like internal git or ftp

Comment: What is the reason that you set up the proxy for?

Comment: Maybe you can try to run this command `Set-InternetProxy -Proxy myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80`, refer to [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-function-Get-cba2abf5)

Comment: I will try set-internetProxy. What do you mean by "what the reason is" because our company is behind proxy and I can not reach azure without it. Easy as that

Comment: Does the way above work?

Comment: `Set-InternetProxy` does not work unfortunately

Comment: Do you enable it with the command `Set-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name ProxyEnable -Value 1` when you set it? And `$reg = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"`

Comment: I do not understand, The sample from this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-function-Get-cba2abf5) is like `C:\Users\de313e\Set-InternetProxy.ps1 myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80` before i needed to set execution policy, as the ps1 file was not signed.

Comment: Maybe you could try to set the environment variable in PowerShell with command `$env:HTTPS_PROXY='myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80'` .

Comment: If the command works to you, please let me know :)

Comment: Hi, I just tried it @CharlesXu and it works. Post your solution as answer and I will accept it

Comment: @kism3t Glad to know it works to you and I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you set the environment variable when you run the command in cmd:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80
```

But it will not work in PowerShell. To set the environment variable in PowerShell, you cloud run the command like this in your issue:

```
$env:HTTPS_PROXY='myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80'
```

Comment: it still doesnt work for me in cmd though, any fix?