# Az login urllib3 [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: azure, networking, https

I am trying to log into Azure on Powershell using "az login". However, I get the following error:

```
<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x04B37760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Any insight on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

> `<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x04B37760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`

This error will occur due to proxy (Internal Proxy or Corporate Proxy).
Try setting the environment variable in command prompt before running to azure login cmdlets:

```bash
set HTTPS_PROXY=myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80
```

> I am trying to log into Azure on Powershell using “az login”

As you said, running `az login` cmdlet in PowerShell for setting the **`HTTPS_PROXY`** in environment variable:

```
$env:HTTPS_PROXY='myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80'
```

Then run the `az login` or `az login --use-device-code` to login to the Azure using CLI in PowerShell.

Refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54978328).