# Azure cli - Get files list from ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to get the list of all the files from ADLS using Az cli. Can someone share some insight on where I am doing wrong or share resources to troubleshoot.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please share the `CLI Command` which you are trying.

Comment: Hi @Harshitha, here is the command I am using - az storage fs access show -p dir -f storageaccountname --account-name containername --account-key "alphanumerickey"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x04B37760>: Failed to
> establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The above error occurs due to proxy (Internal Proxy or Corporate Proxy).
Before using the az login cmdlets, try setting the environment variable below in your command prompt:-

```bash
set HTTPS_PROXY=myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80
```

I logged into my Azure account successfully by running `az login` command like below:-

```
az login
```

Output:-

[image]

Then, I tried your code and got the result below :-

**Code:-**

```
az storage fs access show -p </path/to/directory> -f <>file_system_name> --account-name <account_name> --account-key <account_key>
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Additionally, You can get the list of all the files from ADLS using Az cli with the command below:-

**Code:-**

```
az storage fs file list --path </path/to/directory> --file-system <file_system_name> --account-name <account-name> --account-key <account_key>
```

I got the list of all my files from ADLS using the above command as below,

**Output :-**

[image]

[image]

**References:-**

[azure - Az login urllib3 [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709647/az-login-urllib3-errno-11001-getaddrinfo-failed) By Vijaya

[azure login in cmd works but powershell fails - behind company proxy - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978328/azure-login-in-cmd-works-but-powershell-fails-behind-company-proxy) By Charles Xu