# Azure CLI Powershell logging into account

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, command-line-interface

I am using the latest CLI version 2.53.1

After authentication in the browser window. Powershell displays an error:

<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D7302F9090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

[image]

Comment: Set up the Http proxy as environment variable by running the command `$env:HTTPS_PROXY='myProxy.a200.mh.gro:80'`in powershell. Then run `az login`. Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997706/19991670)

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur due to proxy (Internal Proxy or Corporate Proxy).
Likely you are in a professional setting and companies use proxy and block Internet as the default route.
In order to speak correctly with Azure, you need to specify that calls should redirect via your provy.

As already mentioned within the comment, you can set up an environment variable for HTTPS.

```
$env:HTTPS_PROXY='<proxy address>:<port>'
```

With it you will be able to login, but some commands later may pose issues, so you may want to directly set the HTTP one as well:

```
$env:HTTP_PROXY='<proxy address>:<port>'
```

If it's only a one-shot, you are done. If you are doing it often, you can set any environment variable permanently with

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "<value variable>", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

After that, each time your user runs az login, it will use the proxy by default